# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 Issue

Tags: android, android-resources

I am getting this error in a class that I have setup, I am new to android development and would appreciate finding out how to debug this error, in eclipse.
I have looked at many stack overflow posts regarding this issue but none has helped me solve the problem.

```
public class LeftRightSliderFragmentController extends BaseSliderFragmentController
{
    public LeftRightSliderFragmentController()
    {
    super();
    }
    public LeftRightSliderFragmentController(int titleRes)
    {

    super(R.string.left_and_right);
    }
```

In my strings.xml

I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">SliderExample</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="left_and_right">Left and Right</string>
</resources>
```

In the baseclass I have

```
public class BaseSliderFragmentController extends SlidingFragmentActivity
{

   private int mTitleRes;
   protected RSSFeedFragmentController mFrag;

    public BaseSliderFragmentController(int titleRes)
    {
       mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    public BaseSliderFragmentController()
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //New Change EDIT
            String h = "Hello"
    setTitle(h);
```

Essentially I am not sure why this issue would come up as well I am not exactly sure where this issue is coming up either. I am wondering if there is a way to debug to get to the line of code where this is happening so I can investigate. I believe it has to do with the setTitle possibly?

```
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sliderexample/com.example.sliderexample.FragmentControllers.LeftRightSliderFragmentController}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-06 02:58:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(4879):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
```

EDIT: Made the change in the code new result new Error

03-06 03:33:05.034: E/AndroidRuntime(6336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 03:33:05.034: E/AndroidRuntime(6336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sliderexample/com.example.sliderexample.FragmentControllers.LeftRightSliderFragmentController}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xa

Issue is  I do not know where this error occurs anyone know how to get to that line using the debugger?.... I also searched this up on the stack nothing appears to be able to be useful enough to help me.

Comment: For debugging: set debugging points on the left of the class, next to the line numbers by double clicking. After setting some of them run the program in debug mode and press the second yellow arrow from left to go line by line through your code. Just do that slow and keep looking at the variables. If there appears an exception in the variables box, you know where you have to change something.

Your code: Maybe you just posted to less code or I don't get it, but in the first code box you call a method called "LeftRightSliderFragmentController" and push a int variable but don't use it inside?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Yours constructor with arguments is never called. So mTitleRes equals 0, and android cannot find this resourse. You shouldn't use constructors to pass arguments to the activity. Only default constructor will be called. You should initialize mTitleRes with default value in base activity, or make base activity abstract, create abstract method getTitleRes(), and override it in LeftRightSliderFragmentController. Then use setTitle(getTitleRes()). Or just initialize mTitleRes by other value in descendants. Everithing depend on how you use this activities. Anyway, LeftRightSliderFragmentController(int titleRes) won't be called, when activity is created.

Comment: Okay so if did what you said and now I get the same error with this variation, #0xa ? I have also searched up that error. What I did was I just set a default value of setTitle("Hello"); So that the constructors didn't need to be run.

Comment: Then the problem is probably somewhere else. Try to use line by line debug to find out where the bug is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
<string name="left_and_right">Left and Right</string>
```

Instead, use

```
<integer name="integer_name">integer_value</integer>
```

and if you want to use that string value, use following statement to get string

```
getString(R.string.left_and_right);
```